# Camera Preview in android showing Runtime error

Tags: android, camera

This is the code i used to have camera preview in my app, but it shows a java runtime error but not specifies at which the line the error is at. I found this code on https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Camera/Preview/,which was given as a solution for one of the questions regarding camera preview, but it shows a blank screen and the app terminates. Any help will be appreciated.

```
package com.example.smartmeasure;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class CameraPreview extends Activity {
    private SurfaceView preview=null;
    private SurfaceHolder previewHolder=null;
    private Camera camera=null;
    private boolean inPreview=false;
    private boolean cameraConfigured=false;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera_preview);
    preview=(SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
    previewHolder=preview.getHolder();
    previewHolder.addCallback(surfaceCallback);
    previewHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    camera=Camera.open();
    startPreview();
    }
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
    if (inPreview) {
    camera.stopPreview();
    }
    camera.release();
    camera=null;
    inPreview=false;
    super.onPause();
    }
    private Camera.Size getBestPreviewSize(int width, int height,
    Camera.Parameters parameters) {
    Camera.Size result=null;
    for (Camera.Size size : parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes()) {
    if (size.width<=width && size.height<=height) {
    if (result==null) {
    result=size;
    }
    else {
    int resultArea=result.width*result.height;
    int newArea=size.width*size.height;
    if (newArea>resultArea) {
    result=size;
    }
    }
    }
    }
    return(result);
    }
    private void initPreview(int width, int height) {
    if (camera!=null && previewHolder.getSurface()!=null) {
    try {
    camera.setPreviewDisplay(previewHolder);
    }
    catch (Throwable t) {
    Log.e("PreviewDemo-surfaceCallback",
    "Exception in setPreviewDisplay()", t);
    Toast
    .makeText(CameraPreview.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
    .show();
    }
    if (!cameraConfigured) {
    Camera.Parameters parameters=camera.getParameters();
    Camera.Size size=getBestPreviewSize(width, height,
    parameters);
    if (size!=null) {
    parameters.setPreviewSize(size.width, size.height);
    camera.setParameters(parameters);
    cameraConfigured=true;
    }
    }
    }
    }
    private void startPreview() {
    if (cameraConfigured && camera!=null) {
    camera.startPreview();
    inPreview=true;
    }
    }
    SurfaceHolder.Callback surfaceCallback=new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // no-op -- wait until surfaceChanged()
    }
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder,
    int format, int width,
    int height) {
    initPreview(width, height);
    startPreview();
    }
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // no-op
    }
    };
}
```

This is the Error:

```
05-27 10:34:37.812: E/AndroidRuntime(2559): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 05-27 10:34:37.812: E/AndroidRuntime(2559): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.smartmeasure/com.example.smartmeasure.CameraPreview}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout 05-27 10:34:37.812: E/AndroidRuntime(2559): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
```

This is the xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="241dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: please post your stacktrace.

Comment: 05-27 10:34:37.812: E/AndroidRuntime(2559): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-27 10:34:37.812: E/AndroidRuntime(2559): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.smartmeasure/com.example.smartmeasure.CameraPreview}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout
05-27 10:34:37.812: E/AndroidRuntime(2559):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
This is the logcat error i get everytime i try run it

Comment: Post your XML code for activity_camera_preview layout file

Comment: post exception stack

Comment: @AlokNair and PreethiRao I have edited the question to include the xml details. JiangYD may I know what you mean by exception stack?

Answer (score 0):

`camera_preview` is `FrameLayout` and you are casting it into `SurfaceView` thats the error ..cast it into `FrameLayout`

Comment: We cannot cast it to FrameLayout i guess, because all the further operations like getHolder() are based on SurfaceView. Also I tried to change it the other way in xml file, but it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

You are casting FrameLayout to SurfaceView in your Activity onCreate, put SurfaceView instead of FrameLayout in XML and then name its id to camera_preview and initialize in Activity.

Your XML code will look like this after editing:

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

   <SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="241dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Sorry, but this did not help. Now it shows a different error of not being able to resume activity.

Comment: 05-27 12:22:12.773: E/AndroidRuntime(3197): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.smartmeasure/com.example.smartmeasure.CameraPreview}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
05-27 12:22:12.773: E/AndroidRuntime(3197):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2124)

Comment: Calling Camera.open() throws an exception if the camera is already in use by another application, so we wrap it in a try block.

Comment: Now it shows error in the onPause and Camera.open(), block and stops. I tried putting a catch statement there as well and it shows the error there.

Comment: 05-27 12:47:59.671: E/AndroidRuntime(3820): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-27 12:47:59.671: E/AndroidRuntime(3820): android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {com.example.smartmeasure/com.example.smartmeasure.CameraPreview} did not call through to super.onPause()

Comment: Also in your solution, may I know what myCameraPreview and camId are?

Comment: Post your new updated code and share it using pastie.org or pastebin.com

Comment: You have not implemented the suggestion that I gave in the code I shared through pastebin. Also error in onPause is because you have not called super.onPause() in onPause method

Comment: Try this code http://pastie.org/10209629 I have update your code with my suggestions.

Comment: It says failed to open camera, as in the catch block of onResume(), also it still shows the catch messages in onPause and Camera.open(...). Here is the error:
CameraBase(25937): An error occurred while connecting to camera: 0
05-27 15:41:23.307: E/SmartMeasure(25937): failed to open Camera
05-27 15:41:23.309: W/System.err(25937): java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
at... com.example.smartmeasure.CameraPreview.onResume(CameraPreview.java:30)

Comment: Also could it be a device error? I have tried it on Android 2.3.6 and 4.4.4. It doesn't work on any of them.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add on to the suggestions above, we are supposed to camera user permissions in AndroidManifest.xml file to access the camera. The permission lines are:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```